# assign value of html textbox to title of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

line 1:

```
<input id="Text1" type="text" /><input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" /><br />
```

line 2:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://search.twitter.com/search?q=#msdhoni">#msdhoni</a>
```

What I want- when a user input some thing in text box (in line 1) that should become the title of the div (in line 2) on click of the botton (in line 1). Actually want to replace #msdhoni everywhere in code with the text input in the textbox.

Jquery code I m using:(Please suggest the change in this code to make this possible)

```
String.prototype.linkify=function(){
return this.replace(/[A-Za-z]+:\/\/[A-Za-z0-9-_]+\.[A-Za-z0-9-_:%&;\?\/.=]+/g,function(m){
    return m.link(m);
});
};
String.prototype.linkuser=function(){
return this.replace(/[@]+[A-Za-z0-9-_]+/g,function(u){
    return u.link("http://twitter.com/"+u.replace("@",""));
});
};
String.prototype.linktag=function(){
return this.replace(/[]+[A-Za-z0-9-_]+/,function(t){
    return t;
});
};

var showTweetLinks='none';
function fetch_tweets(elem){
elem = $(elem);

keyword = escape(elem.attr('title'));


num=elem.attr('class').split(' ').slice(-1);

var url = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=" +keyword+ "&rpp=" + num + "&callback=?";
$.getJSON(url,function(json){
    $(json.results).each(function(){
        var tTime=new Date(Date.parse(this.created_at));
        var cTime=new Date();
        var sinceMin=Math.round((cTime-tTime)/60000);
        if(sinceMin==0){
            var sinceSec=Math.round((cTime-tTime)/1000);
            if(sinceSec<10)
                var since='less than 10 seconds ago';
            else if(sinceSec<20)
                var since='less than 20 seconds ago';
            else
                var since='half a minute ago';
        }
        else if(sinceMin==1){
            var sinceSec=Math.round((cTime-tTime)/1000);
            if(sinceSec==30)
                var since='half a minute ago';
            else if(sinceSec<60)
                var since='less than a minute ago';
            else
                var since='1 minute ago';
        }
        else if(sinceMin<45)
            var since=sinceMin+' minutes ago';
        else if(sinceMin>44&&sinceMin<60)
            var since='about 1 hour ago';
        else if(sinceMin<1440){
            var sinceHr=Math.round(sinceMin/60);
            if(sinceHr==1)
                var since='about 1 hour ago';
            else
                var since='about '+sinceHr+' hours ago';
        }
        else if(sinceMin>1439&&sinceMin<2880)
            var since='1 day ago';
        else{
            var sinceDay=Math.round(sinceMin/1440);
            var since=sinceDay+' days ago';
        }
        var tweetBy='<a class="tweet-user" target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/'+this.from_user+'">@'+this.from_user+'</a> <span class="tweet-time">'+since+'</span>';
        if(showTweetLinks.indexOf('reply')!=-1)
            tweetBy=tweetBy+' &middot; <a class="tweet-reply" target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/?status=@'+this.from_user+' &in_reply_to_status_id='+this.id+'&in_reply_to='+this.from_user+'">Reply</a>';
        if(showTweetLinks.indexOf('view')!=-1)
            tweetBy=tweetBy+' &middot; <a class="tweet-view" target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/'+this.from_user+'/statuses/'+this.id+'">View Tweet</a>';
        if(showTweetLinks.indexOf('rt')!=-1)
            tweetBy=tweetBy+' &middot; <a class="tweet-rt" target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/?status=RT @'+this.from_user+' '+escape(this.text.replace(/&quot;/g,'"'))+'&in_reply_to_status_id='+this.id+'&in_reply_to='+this.from_user+'">RT</a>';
        var tweet='<div class="tweet"><div class="tweet-left"><a target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/'+this.from_user+'"><img width="48" height="48" alt="'+this.from_user+' on Twitter" src="'+this.profile_image_url+'" /></a></div><div class="tweet-right"><p class="text">'+this.text.linkify().linkuser().linktag().replace(/<a/g,'<a target="_blank"')+'<br />'+tweetBy+'</p></div><br style="clear: both;" /></div>';
        elem.append(tweet);
    });
});
return(false);
}
$(function(){
showTweetLinks=showTweetLinks.toLowerCase();
if(showTweetLinks.indexOf('all')!=-1)
    showTweetLinks='reply,view,rt';
$('.twitStream').each(function(){
    fetch_tweets(this);
});
});
```

Comment: Please consider reading your question back to yourself. You speak of a `<div>` on Line 2 (but I only see an Anchor), you also mention replacing `#msdhoni` everywhere in code (unsure what that means, looks like a DOM Id, if so there can only be one `#msdhoni`). Also, your code to make a DIV [I assume contain, because a div has no title] the text from a textbox, is actually some code to search twitter and return tweets???

Comment: your code and you markup dont really match .... the code is doing a lots more then the markup suggests .....

Answer (score 1):

Your question is all over the place - the question / HTML / JavaScript dont match up .... below is a way to update the `href` and text of an `anchor` (not a `div`) on the click of a button

```
<input id="Text1" type="text" /><input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" /><br />
<a id="Link1" target="_blank" href="http://search.twitter.com/search?q=#msdhoni">#msdhoni</a>
```

JavaScript :

```
$('#Button1').click(function() {
    $('#Link1').attr('href',"http://search.twitter.com/search?q=#" + $('#Text1').val());
    $('#Link1').text("#" + $('#Text1').val());
});
```

Note: You need to add an `ID` to the anchor to make this code work

Comment: I am going to upvote, I considered answering with the same thing. His code was too unclear for me to waste my time. This is what he SAID he wanted to do, based on his HTML markup its the only thing he really can do, his provided Javascript pertained to something else.

Comment: @MikeL. totally agree ... not really sure if this is what the OP wants ... i suspect the code they have in the question is a cut and paste and that the OP really has no idea what it does !!! ta for the +1

Comment: missed <div class="twitStream 5" id="tweets" title="#msdhoni" > in line 2